# Accessing CSV Data with D3.js using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, csv, d3.js

I am using Django to create my website, and would also like to incorporate D3.js to graph some data I have stored in CSV files. Normally I am able to access the CSV file using:

```
{% static "data/values.csv" %}
```

so if I wanted to link it on my site I would do the following:

```
<a href="{% static "data/values.csv" %}">CSV File</a>
```

However, before I start to graphs anything I would like to output the vales stored in the CSV files using JavaScript's console.log function, like so:

```
<script>
d3.csv("{% static "data/values.csv" %}", function (myArrayofObjects){
    myArrayofObjects.forEach(function (d){
        console.log(d.x + ", " + d.y);
    });
});
</script>
```

However, in my browser's (Chrome) console all I see is

```
10 undefined, undefined
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks.

**Edit**

Thanks for the help, but I was over thinking it. Turns out I should have typed:

```
console.log(d.Date + ", " + d.Value);
```

instead of

```
console.log(d.x + ", " + d.y);
```

because those were my headers (or first lines) on my CSV file.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but you're  not calling the columns in the csv file with your javascript? **csvData.getAllResponseHeaders()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csvData;
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#btnGET").click(function() {
            csvData = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.sites.com/data/sample_file.csv",
                dataType: "text/csv",
                success: function (result) {
                   alert(result);
                   alert("done!"+ csvData.getAllResponseHeaders())
                 }
            });
       });
    })
```

This should work though for you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Do you mind up voting my answer if it helped?